# assigning permanent custom paths to anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, anaconda, pythonpath

This question has been asked, but oddly enough the answers are out of date or not sufficient.

I have installed anaconda, I have setup an environment running py2.7. I launch a win7 cmd prompt and type activate python27 (my custom python environment). I then import sys and then sys.path to see what my python paths are. They all point to variations of E:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\....

I want to add a custom path to this list so that it becomes permanent. Doing sys.path.append is not good enough as its not permanent. I have been reading that adding PYTHONPATH to the environment variables is not done any more, and that I should be adding my custom paths to the PATH system variables.

So could someone advise where and how I can assign my custom paths.

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks to my instructor I found this to work for me.

open a command prompt (just regular win cmd) and add a path like this where you see the J:\pythonTest you can add your own path this will put it into your path.

SETX PYTHONPATH "%PYTHONPATH%;J:\pythonTest"

One thing I noticed, because I had been trying all sort of ways to solve this problem, my user variables and system variables and a few duplicates of my custom path. I would advise removing them once you run the above command. I suggest removing them because I think I discovered some conflicts and my modules wouldn't run, removing the duplicates seemed to fix this conflict.